# Best practice for bringing together GWT source into a WAR using Maven

Tags: gwt, maven-2, package, structure, war

I'm currently in the process of splitting our rather over grown project down into its consecutive parts. The intention is that each separation becomes its own Maven project. There will be a parent Maven project that's responsible for ensuring all the correct parts are compiled and global properties are shared.

With this in mind, our GWT code will be self-contained within its own project, and will be compiled using the GWT Maven plugin. Another project will be responsible for creating the WAR file, probably using the Cargo plugin as it's likely we'll need to merge web.xml files.

Here lies the question, how do I get the compiled GWT source from the one project, into the WAR file that'll be created by the another project?

What further complicates matters, is that there'll be feature extensions provided by further projects which will also be in their own projects, and these to will have compiled GWT source that'll need to be included into the WAR.

Has anyone had experience of this? Any pointers to online resources or best practices? Should I be looking to structure it differently?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a similar layout (with slightly over 20 Maven modules). The webapp itself is composed of 3 projects: shared, client and server.

1. The shared module is a simple JAR with our RequestFactory interfaces and other code that's shared between the client and server.
2. The client module has packaging=jar so it's seen as a Java project in Eclipse, it runs the gwt-maven-plugin in the prepare-package phase, and we use the assembly plugin to package the JS code into a ZIP. The module depends on shared both without classifier and with classifier=sources.
3. The server module is the webapp, and it uses the ZIP of the client module as a war overlay.

Ideally, the gwt-maven-plugin would provide a new packaging specific to GWT, and a specific goal to output it in the war, similar to the [flexmojos](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/flex-dev-sect-creating-with-archetype.html); but the above is almost what I would personally call the "perfect project layout".

**EDIT:** I'm working on Maven archetypes using a similar layout: https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes

Comment: Thank you Thomas, this does sound very similar to our project. In step one, I assume you use no plugin, but simply package shared as a jar and source jar. Step two, could you elaborate on what the assembly plugin is? And step three, do you use the maven-war-plugin plugin?

Comment: There's absolutely nothing special in the shared module, you're right. [Maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) allows you to attach additional artifacts to your module. And in the server module, the maven-war-plugin calls out the ZIP from the client module as a [war overlay](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html). Note that we could have used packaging=war for the client module too, but we'd have had to exclude the `WEB-INF/classes`, and we don't have a `src/main/webapp`, so we opted for packaging=jar instead.

Comment: Excellent, you've answered many of the questions I was having. Now to put it all into practice...

Comment: In the client project, I've specified the dependency on the shared jar as compile, and on the shared source jar as provided. If I now make any change within the shared project, the gwt plugin within the client project doesn't pick up this change and recompile the gwt source. I have to first clean the client project and then it will recompile the gwt source. Is this also your experience?

Comment: That might very-well be the case if you use `mvn gwt:run`. In Eclipse, using the GPE, you just have to explicitly add the src/main/java and src/main/resources folders of the shared project to the DevMode's runtime classpath.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer Your solution is something I would eager to use. Can you write something more about it, maybe some detailed steps of creating this project?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes (hot from the press; more to come, and certainly perfectible)